# How to get lastModified property of another website

Tags: node.js, dom, puppeteer, jsdom

[image: This is inspect tool]

When I use the inspect/developer tool in chrome I can find the last modified date from browser but I want to see the same date in my nodeJS application.

I have already tried

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.tbsnews.net/economy/bsec-chairman-stresses-restoring-investor-confidence-mutual-funds-500126');
const names = page.evaluate( ()=> {
    console.log(document.lastModified);
})
```

Unfortunately this code shows the current time of new DOM creation as we are using newPage(). Can anyone help me ?

I have also tired JSDOM as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you asking?

Comment: I am new to nodeJS and can;t solve the issue.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. This works fine for me, same as the browser. You should `await` your `page.evaluate` though. This is a popular page, so it's probably updated constantly, probably leading you to believe that it's somehow giving you the time that the `newPage()` runs. But if you try a non-popular site, like my github pages landing, you'll see it's correct (I did in fact update it a couple of days ago): ```await page.goto('https://ggorlen.github.io', {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => document.lastModified));``` gives  `09/28/2022 18:55:38`.

Comment: I usually use `const [page] = await browser.pages()` because Puppeteer already has a tab open when you launch it, but I get the same result as with `browser.newPage()`. Why do you need this date anyway, as Dai suggested (provide context)?